# How can i center equations or float?

Tags: equations, horizontal-alignment

I write the following equation and it appears aligned to the left. I have tried with `\centering` and

```
\begin{center}
...
\end{center}
```

but it is still the same. This is what I have done

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper, openright]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, bm, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{equation}
f(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-x^{2}, &\text{if $x < 0$;}\\
\alpha + x, &\text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$;}\\
x^{2}, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}
\end{center}   

\end{document}
```

This is the result

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Comment: The screenshot you posted looks *very different* from the output that's generated by running your code through `pdflatex`. E.g., in your screenshot, there's no `=` symbol after `f(x)`; the curly brace doesn't span all three rows of the array; there's no `+` symbol between `\alpha` and `x` in the middle row of the array; the screenshot uses a non-default font; a non-default equation numbering system is in use. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you use `iwona` light, condensed, math fonts, result is as expected. Of course, you should delete `center` environment around equation as other people have already mentioned:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper, openright]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[light, condensed, math]{iwona}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, bm}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
    \begin{equation}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
    -x^{2},     & \text{if $x < 0$;}\\
    \alpha + x, & \text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$;}\\
    x^{2},      & \text{otherwise.}
       \end{cases}
    \end{equation}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Zarko. In addition to this, I had another error. The error was in using another fourier font package in the preamble `\usepackage{fourier}`, don't put it in MWE so as not to spread out. I have removed it, and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

By default, the `equation` environment centres equations so you don't need the `center` environment. In addition, rather than using `array` you should use the `cases` environment. With these two changes your MWE produces:

[image]

Here is the updated code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper, openright]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, bm, amssymb}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  f(x) = \begin{cases}
            -x^{2}, &\text{if $x < 0$;}\\
            \alpha + x, &\text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$;}\\
            x^{2}, &\text{otherwise.}
          \end{cases}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer, one day to use your start code, you should to delete `\begin{center}...\end{center}` because the enviroment `equation` give the centered formula. And from the correct suggestion of the user @Mico your screenshot is different from the code: I see that the font is **Iwona**.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper, openright]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amsfonts, bm, amssymb}
\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
f(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
-x^{2}, &\text{if $x < 0$;}\\
\alpha + x, &\text{if $0 \leq x \leq 1$;}\\
x^{2}, &\text{otherwise.}
\end{array}
\right.
\end{equation}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for answering. The error was when using the package `\usepackage[light, condensed, math]{iwona}` which I also had in the preamble of my document, but for simplicity I did not attach it.

By removing the math option from the `iwona` package. Leaving it out of the way `\usepackage[light, condensed]{iwona}` I got the solution to the problem.